# How to show a splash screen

Tags: vb.net

I want a splash screen to appear after some seconds before the login screen appears

```
Public Class Splash_Screen
    Private Sub Splash_Screen_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Splash_Screen.OnClick.LogIn.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function OnClick() As Object
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: The VB App Framework includes a no-code splash screen.  Just assign it via Project->Properties Application tab

Answer (score 1):

No code is needed. Right click somewhere in "Solution Explorer" and click Add=>New Item=>Windows Forms=>Splash Screen. After go to your project properties, Application tab and at bottom of page select your Splash Screen in last drop down list.
[image]

Or if you want add it by simple Windows Form, use `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)`.
This will freeze your app for 3 seconds.